# postgresql count all entries created on a particular date?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to count all entries created on a particular date in postgresql. The table has a created_date field which of type time stamp without time zone , One of the entries in created_date looks like this 2020-08-18 12:26:22.641.

`select count(*) from table where created_date='2020-08-18*'`
This is what i try but that does not work.

How can i count is there something like contain or regex match for this scenario??
Thanks!!

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-datetime.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most efficient way is to use a range condition:

```
select count(*)
from the_table
where created_date >= date '2020-08-18'
  and created_date < date '2020-08-19';
```

Another option is to cast the timestamp to a `date` value:

```
select count(*)
from the_table
where created_date::date = date '2020-08-18'
```